# AccessDeniedException when creating a AWS CodePipeline using Github as provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

So I have an awseducate account and I am trying to create a CodePipeline in AWS with Github as provider, but whenever I select Github as the provider I get this error
User: ... is not authorized to perform: ... with an explicit deny

Hope you can help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AWS Educlate Starter Accounts are **very limited**. You can check what is allowed below:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

The error you are getting means that what you want to do is explicitly denied as part of these limitations.